# How to extract 2+ character words from string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I assume some sort of regex would be used to accomplish this?

*I need to get it where each word consists of 2 or more characters, start with a letter, and the remaining characters consist of letters, digits, and underscores.*

This is the code I currently have, although it isn't very close to my desired output:

```
while (my $line=<>) {
  # remove leading and trailing whitespace
  $line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
  $line = lc $line;
  @array = split / /, $line;
  foreach my $a (@array){
    $a =~ s/[\$#@~!&*()\[\];.,:?^ `\\\/]+//g;
    push(@list, "$a");
  }
}
```

A sample input would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
# This line will print a hello world line.
print "Hello world!\n";
exit 0;
```

And the desired output would be (alphabetical order):

```
bin
exit 
hello
hello
line
perl
print
print
strict
this
use
usr
will
world
```

Comment: Did you try a pattern like `\b[a-z][a-z0-9_]+` ...? Add parenthesis around it to capture what it matches, and `i` modifier for case-Insensitive; can add it with the pattern itself as well, `(?i)pattern`

Comment: `split / /` is not the same as `split ' '`, read the documentation (you want to use the latter). Don't use `$a` as it is a predefined variable used by sort. Don't quote a single variable `"$a"` that is unnecessary. Also unnecessary to make a new array `@list` since it will be identical to `@array`. You change the original array inside the for loop. Don't try and make a list of ALL the characters you don't want, when you have a limited set of characters you want. You might just use `\W` instead (the inverse of letters, numbers and underscore)

Comment: What do you do with hyphenated words? `apple-eater`?

Comment: Why is there `bin` (not in the input?), `hello` twice (there's actually `hello` and `Hello`) -- (etc, there is a lot more) ...?

Comment: @zdim Shebang line, plus `lc` in the Perl code.

Comment: @TLP Um, I don't understand -- their "_sample input_" has none of that? No two `print`s either... I think they aren't showing the correct input

Comment: Maybe he forgot to show the shebang line. `# This line will print a hello world line.
print "He...` Those are 2 prints

Comment: I don't see the `0` though. And I don't see the part of the code that selects only words with 2+ characters.

Comment: @TLP Ah, ok, there are two prints.  And it's all lower-cased? Alittle messy, but it seems clear what they want, at least.  "_don't see the part of the code that selects only words with 2+ characters_" -- yeah, no such thing

Comment: @zdim `$line = lc $line`. I think it checks out, except for the missing shebang. And the things I mentioned, the requirements in the text that are not in the code.

Comment: @TLP Ah, their code is supposed to do exactly this ... ugh, didn't figure that out; I thought it was some larger program ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my @matches = $string =~ /\b([a-z][a-z0-9_]+)/ig;
```

If case-insensitive operation need be applied only to a subpattern, can [embed it](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Embedding-comments-and-modifiers-in-a-regular-expression)

```
/... \b((?i)[a-z][a-z0-9_]+) .../
```

(or, it can be turned off after the subpattern, `(?i)pattern(?-i)`)

That `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` goes as `\w`, a "*word character*", if that's indeed exactly what is needed.

The above regex picks words as required without a need to first split the line on space, done in the shown program. Can apply it on the whole line (or on the whole text for that matter), perhaps after the shown stripping of the various special characters.<sup>†</sup>

There is a question of some other cases -- how about hyphens? Apostrophes? Tilde? Those aren't found in identifiers, while this appears to be intended to process programming text, but comments are included; what other legitimate characters may there be?

---

*Note on [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split)-ing on whitespace*

The shown `split / /, $line` splits on exactly that one space.  Better is `split /\s+/, $line` -- or, better yet is to use `split`'s special pattern `split ' ', $line`: split on any number of any consecutive whitespace, and where leading and trailing spaces are discarded.

---

<sup>†</sup>  The shown example is correctly processed as desired by the given regex alone

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Path::Tiny qw(path);  # convenience, to slurp the file

my $fn = shift // die "Usage: $0 filename\n";

my @matches = sort map { lc } 
    path($fn)->slurp =~ /\b([a-z][a-z0-9_]+)/ig; 

say for @matches;
```

I threw in sorting and lower-casing to match the sample code in the question but all processing is done with the shown regex on the file's content in a string.

Output is as desired (except that `line` and `world` here come twice, what is correct).

Note that `lc` can be applied on the string with the file content, which is then processed with the regex, what is more efficient.  While this is in principle not the same in this case it may be

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -wE'$f = shift // die "Need filename\n"; 
    @m = sort lc(path($f)->slurp) =~ /\b([a-z]\w+)/ig; 
    say for @m'
```

Here I actually used `\w`. Adjust to the actual character to match, if different.

Comment: Doesn't the `\w` character class fit the description pretty well? Also, do you need `\b`?

Comment: @TLP I do need `\b`, I think (so it doesn't match from after the beginningof a word that would otherwise not qualify, like starting with a number; not a valid identifier but they're considering comments etc)  --- yes, `\w` matches, but I don't know what other details may not be given (yet) so I spelled it out.  Adding a commnt for that...

Answer (score 2):

Curiously, this can be done with one of those long, typical Perl one-liners

```
$ perl -lwe'print for sort grep /^\pL/ && length > 1, map { split /\W+/ } map lc, <>' a.txt
bin
exit
hello
hello
line
line
perl
print
print
strict
this
use
usr
will
world
world
```

Lets go through that and see what we can learn. This line reads from right to left.

- `a.txt` is the argument file to read
- `<>` is the diamond operator, reading the lines from the file. Since this is list context, it will exhaust the file handle and return all the lines.
- `map lc`, short for `map { lc($_) }` will apply the `lc` function on all the lines and return the result.
- `map { split /\W+/ }` is a multi-purpose operation. It will remove the unwanted characters (the non-word characters), and also split the line there, and return a list of all those words.
- `grep /^\pL/ && length > 1` sorts out strings that begin with a letter `\pL` and are longer than 1 and returns them.
- `sort` sorts alphabetically the list coming in from the right and returns it left
- `for` is a for-loop, applied to the incoming list, in the post-fix style.
- `print` is short for `print $_`, and it will print once for each list item in the for loop.
- The `-l` switch in the perl command will "fix" line endings for us (remove them from input, add them in output). This will make the print pretty at the end.

I won't say this will produce a perfect result, but you should be able to pick up some techniques to finish your own program.

Comment: Must "_start with a letter_" they say.  Their regex does not exclude quite all non-word characters, `-` for one (perhaps by omission)

Comment: @zdim Oh right... yes, `grep /^\pL/` maybe.

Comment: @zdim `-` is part of `\W`.

Comment: What I meant is that their regex (the one that removes various non-word chars) doesn't have `-` so perhaps that should stay, but then they don't mention it so better not worry.  (And that'd be easy to fix with `\W` -> `[^-\w]` if needed)